# shuffle: influence of sort

Tags: perl, sorting, random

Does the line with the `sort` result in a more random array or is the `sort` here only a waste?

```
use List::Util qw(shuffle);


@random1 = shuffle sort keys %vocables;

@random2 = shuffle keys %vocables;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If placing a sort before the shuffle made a difference, then shuffle would be broken. Since shuffle works, the sort is a waste of processor time.  The whole point of a good shuffle is to eliminate any pre-existing ordering of the elements.

Answer (score 10):

The 'sort' does not make it any more random and is a waste